# Reading a DataTable from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

i Have an ajax function that fill a DataTable from an sql query and return it my prolem is that i can't find a solution to read that DataTable from javascript is their any particular way to do that ?

The code :

```
 [WebMethod]
public static DataTable SendOnlineContacts(int ClientID)
{

    string query = " Select fr.FRIEND_ID,cl.USER_NAME,cl.PROFILE_PIC "
                   +" from clients cl inner join friends fr on cl.CLIENT_ID =fr.FRIEND_ID "
                    +"  where fr.CLIENT_ID= "+ ClientID ;
    return  new SQLHelper(SQLHelper.ConnectionStrings.WebSiteConnectionString).getQueryResult(query);
}
```

SQLHelper(SQLHelper.ConnectionStrings.WebSiteConnectionString).getQueryResult(query) is a class that i created just to simplify my work and this function return a DataTable by default

Comment: your ajax code please

Comment: @Sora how do you return this to your client side?

Comment: i edited my code please check and i call my function from client side but on success i don't know how to read the DataTable

Comment: check this link this solution working for me. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19396/Convert-ASP-NET-DataTable-to-JSON-to-use-a-DataTab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use standard formats to exchange data between the server side and the client side. The .net datatable is a powerfull and complex object. But the client does not need the datatable itself, rather the client needs its data.
So I think the point is: how to pass data from the server to the client.

Working with strings is a simple solution if the data structure you manage is a plain structure. Though, if you want more flexibility and a more generic approach, string manipulation could be easy become a hell.
So I think that using a structured format (e.g. JSON) could be a better solution.

Eventually, you need to present data to the client. I usually use [Jayrock](http://jayrock.berlios.de/) to present data in JSON format to the client. Have a look.

The steps to implement your solution could be:

1. [*server side*] Implement an handler that: retrieves data from your backend, serializes them into JSON and exposes them
2. [*client side*] Implement a javascript client (a Jayrock proxy if you like this solution) that calls the handler, retrieves the data and renders them in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a great way to solve this :) and it might be helpful to other users so i'll post it as an answer 
if the DataTable return multiple row i would read each row as a string and put a ';' at the end of  it than on every column of that row i would put ',' so i can read them later i'll show that in code

Server Side :

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SendOnlineContacts(int ClientID)
{
    string result="";
string query = " Select fr.FRIEND_ID,cl.USER_NAME,cl.PROFILE_PIC "
               +" from clients cl inner join friends fr on cl.CLIENT_ID =fr.FRIEND_ID "
                +"  where fr.CLIENT_ID= "+ ClientID ;
DataTable Dt= SQLHelper(SQLHelper.ConnectionStrings.WebSiteConnectionString).getQueryResult(query);
 if(Dt.Rows.Count>0)
  {
      for(int i=0;i<Dt.Rows.Count;i++)
    {
        result+=Dt.Rows[i][0]+","+Dt.Rows[i][1]+";" ;
    }
   return result;
   }
}
```

Client Side

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ChatPageTest.aspx/SendOnlineContacts',
    data: '{ClientID:"' + ClientID+ '"}',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      var Res=data.d.split(';');
       for(i=0;i<Res.length;i++)
       {
          var Fres=Res[i].split(',');

       }
    });
```

Comment: While it works at the moment, once something in the returned data will contain either "," or ";" your code will break. This solution is not good, more of a hackish way around.

Comment: i just put "," ";" for saying that you could split a row by a character and the data in the row by another character we could use any other special character and yes you are right but i used those 2 character bcs my dataTable does not contains any of those